# create "good" mesh from terrestrical laser scan point cloud data and simplify it

Tags: meshlab

first off, im all new to meshlab.
i come from an archiviz background and i am also an architect, not a coder or mathematician or anyhting ... so what i know about 3d, i know from doing it, trial and error kind and learning by myself - so please be patient with me :)

**now for the problem:**

given is a set of points, about 3.5 million if i reckon correctly, it comes from a terrestrical laser scan of a larger area and is in a 1x1m raster...

there is also a digital "orthofoto" as geotiff and some buildings as shape data availeable...

normally i would use vectorworks to create the digital site model but the amount of points is too much :)
vectorworks can't handle it in a proper way,it laggs freezes and so on...

i have been looking for a solution on how to create a mesh from the point cloud data and how to texture it and found meshlab... so far i was able to import the point cloud data (simple ptx format with x y and z...)

then i played with the commands

"recompute vertex normals"

and

"suraface reconstruction screened poisson"

the result is very poly heavy and has some artifacts where there are polygons that are over or under the surface which creates some shading problems and most likely also texturing/UV issues...
i also played a a bit with the "quadric edge collapse dicimation" to simplify the mesh.. but the artifacts stick

**so the question is**

how to create a proper mesh without artifacts and whats the best way to simplify it and reduce polygons without loosing too much of the acutal elevation data ?

next steps include putting the geotiff texture on it and eventually also add the house models...

would be nice if someone has a few tipps for me!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am also new to mesh lab. But I have tested meshlab for similar reasons and to simplify the mesh I used the filter command: Remeshing, Simplification, Reconstruction – Simplification: Clustering Decimation. You then can enter cell size or percentage. The smaller the cell size, the finer the mesh will be and v.v.

For Cleaning and repairing a mesh, and orienting the faces I am also still looking for a proper way. Good Luck*T